# How to open a closed windows form in c#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-control

I would like to reopen a closed windows form in c#.

I actually actively close the form to allow autoIT scripts to run on a different windows application. However I would like to reopen the same form after the scripts are done.

So...

```
this.Close();
.
.
.
Application.Run(new FormTestPage());
```

However this gives me an error that says to use Form.ShowDialogue instead.
I'm unsure how that works.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you need to restart the exe?

Comment: Did you want to Close it, or Hide it?

Comment: I want to close it, since hiding it won't allow the program to shift to another windows form application for the script. I don't think I need to restart the exe? it is just the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close the main form and you started the application with

```
var frm = new MainForm();
Application.Run(frm);
```

Then closing the main form will also close the application. Start the application like this instead

```
var frm = new MainForm();
frm.Show();
Application.Run();
```

Now when the application has to close, you must call `Exit` (because it is not closed automatically anymore):

```
Application.Exit();
```

You can do this in the main form in the `FormClosed` event when you are not just closing the form temporarily.

Now you can reopen the form normaly with:

```
var frm = new MainForm();
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = new FormTestPage();
item.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing this, however I do see a brief image of the form popping up but I cannot actually see it. :S Is there a setting or anything i need to change?

Comment: may be your form call method `Close` in ctor or `FormLoad`/`FormShown` event handlers